# Including Geometry in ModelBuilder Join?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, attribute-joins

I want to perform a join between a feature class and a table and then export the data as a feature class using ArcGIS ModelBuilder.

My current problem is that the geometry is not present in the output.

I have tried 2 methods so far:

1) **Join Field:** (which is supposed to work for Tables or Feature Classes)

2) **Add Join:** Creating a Table View and a Feature Layer from the associated data sources, and performing the Add Join

In each option I have tried the Feature Class (source) both as Input and Join.
The output never contains the Geometry - it is always a Table.

How can I include the Geometry in the output?

Comment: Method 2 should work with the feature layer as input layer and table view as join table. After the join you need to run Copy Features

Comment: @BERA thank you. Copy Features is what I was looking for, this worked. You posted first so if you add an answer with this I will give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 2 should work with the feature layer as input layer and table view as join table. After the join you need to run Copy Features to make it permanent.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a join in modelbuilder, you need to export the joined feature class to make it permanent. You can do this by either using [Copy Features](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-features.htm) or [Feature Class to Feature Class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm) tool.

If you need to understand the actual geometry, make sure you create the new feature class into a geodatabase. Or the other way is to add a new field, and run [Calculate Geometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/calculating-area-length-and-other-geometric-properties.htm) depending on what units you prefer.